# How to load pandas package in an Anki addon?

Tags: python, numpy, anki

I want to use a `numpy` function in an Anki addon that I am forking, but it returns an error when I run Anki (error below). I guess it is because I am using `import numpy`. So how I can use a `numpy` function when the package is not in the original code in the addon. Should I install the package first? If yes, how? Because `pip install` doesn't work in the code and I should probably install package in an environment.

```
Caught exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aqt\progress.py", line 54, in handler
  File "aqt\main.py", line 149, in on_window_init
  File "aqt\main.py", line 197, in setupProfileAfterWebviewsLoaded
  File "aqt\main.py", line 244, in setupProfile
  File "aqt\main.py", line 425, in loadProfile
  File "aqt\hooks_gen.py", line 2985, in __call__
  File "anki\hooks.py", line 34, in runHook
  File "C:\Users\saeed\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\addons21\1807206748\__init__.py", line 37, in start_here
    from . import common as fastwq
  File "C:\Users\saeed\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\addons21\1807206748\common.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .gui import show_about_dialog, show_options  # , check_updates
  File "C:\Users\saeed\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\addons21\1807206748\gui\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .common import *
  File "C:\Users\saeed\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\addons21\1807206748\gui\common.py", line 28, in <module>
    from ..service import service_manager, service_pool
  File "C:\Users\saeed\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\addons21\1807206748\service\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    service_manager = ServiceManager()                             # Service Manager
  File "C:\Users\saeed\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\addons21\1807206748\service\manager.py", line 35, in __init__
    self.update_services()
  File "C:\Users\saeed\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\addons21\1807206748\service\manager.py", line 43, in update_services
    self.web_services, self.local_custom_services = self._get_services_from_files()
  File "C:\Users\saeed\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\addons21\1807206748\service\manager.py", line 78, in _get_services_from_files
    module = importlib.import_module(
  File "C:\Users\saeed\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\addons21\1807206748\utils\importlib.py", line 43, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\saeed\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\addons21\1807206748\service\dict\frdic.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```